# output of function with unknowned size

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, matlab-compiler

I want to define a function in matlab that gives a vector as input and gives local minimals as output in the form of a matrix. but i give this error:Too many output arguments.
here is my code

```
    function [index, value] = localminima(x)
    N = length(x);
    a = [];   
     b = [];   
%     at first a & b witch are index and value, respectively are empty
%     then, in the for loop indexes and values of local minimal are added
%     to a & b.
     for k = 2:N-1,
        if((x(k) < x(k+1)) && (x(k) < x(k-1)))
            a = [a; k];
            b = [b; x(k)];
        end
    end
    [index, value] = [a, b]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want, without loops:

```
d = diff(x);
ind = [false d<0] & [d>0 false];
a = find(ind);
b = x(ind);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to assign the values `a` and `b` to `index` and `value` MATLAB is actually concatenating them into a single vector which it can't assign to two output variables. Instead you could use `index = a; value = b` or just replace the variable names `a` and `b` alltogether with `index` and `value`.

Furthermore, performance will probably improve if you don't use a loop but instead use MATLABs built-in functions and logical indexing, so e.g.

```
function [index, value] = localminima(x)
    dx = diff(x);
    logicalIndex = [ false dx < 0 ] & [ dx > 0 false ];

    index = find(logicalIndex);
    value = x(logicalIndex);
end
```

Comment: Good explanation AND an improved implementation.  But I like Luis's better, your use of `sign` is just adding complexity for no benefit I can see.

Comment: You're correct, I thought that it may add some clarity but performance wise it's of course better to leave it out; I've modified the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`[index, value] = [a, b]` is incorrect.  You should have two separate assignments:

```
index = a;
value = b;
```

To get both `index` and `value` vectors as outputs from your function, you should call the function in MATLAB command windows as

```
>> [index, value] = localminima(x)
```

A bit of an explanation: Both sides of `[index, value] = [a, b]` look similar, but they mean different things.

- `[a, b]` is constructing an `nx2` matrix by concatenating the `nx1` vectors `a` and `b`.
- `[index, value]` is trying to assign the result from the right-hand side of the `=` symbol to two variables: `index` and `value`.  Since `[a,b]` is a single variable, which is a matrix, `[index, value] = [a, b]` is an invalid operation: there is nothing to assign to the variable `value`.
- When you call your function `[index, value] = localminima(x)` and define `index=...` and `value= ...` in your function as two separate variables, then your function will return two outputs. Hence `[index, value] = localminima(x)` will be a valid operation.

Comment: thanks. but i get only he 'index' vector as output.and i dont recieve value vector